Numerically stable half-angle identities
The half-angle identities
$$
\cos\frac{\theta}{2} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos\theta}{2}} \quad
\sin\frac{\theta}{2} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{2}} \quad
$$
suffer from catastrophic cancellation when $\cos(\theta) \simeq \pm 1$. Is there a representation that is more numerically stable?

You could also use $(1+\cos\theta)(1-\cos\theta)=\sin^2\theta$ to replace the factor with catastrophic cancellation.

Thanks @LutzLehmann, that's right. That is in fact how I first got to the identity in my answer: exploit your identity and then some clean up.

If both $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ are available, the following identity is more stable and requires only one square root operation:
$$
\left(\cos \frac{\theta}{2},\ \sin \frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \left \{
\begin{split}
&\pm\mathrm{normalized}[(1 + \cos \theta,\ \sin\theta)]\quad \mathrm{if}\, \cos \theta \geq 0 \\
&\pm\mathrm{normalized}[(\sin \theta,\ 1 - \cos\theta)]\quad \mathrm{if}\, \cos \theta < 0\,.
\end{split}
\right.
$$

If $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$ the sign should be chosen such that $\cos \theta / 2 \geq 0$.

If $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$ the sign should be chosen such that $\sin \theta / 2 \geq 0$.


Alternatively, at the cost of of three trigonometric operations, there is the obvious solution using atan2.
Here is a comparison of the error of the three methods, for float32, with zero error clipped at 1e-9:

The identity comes from the following construction:

where:

$\hat{HAC} = \theta$
$\hat{KAD} = \theta / 2 $
$\overline{AK} = 1 + \cos \theta = \overline{AD} \cos \theta / 2$
$\overline{KD} = \sin \theta = \overline{AD} \sin \theta / 2$

